# Pythonで、横軸が文字列のグラフを作成したい

Tags: python, python3

Pythonで横軸が文字列のグラフを作成したいです。縦軸は数値です。

実験データから作成したdataFrameにて、特定の列を抜き出して、グラフ化したいと思っています。
下記のようなイメージです。LOTを時間のデータ代わりに使います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

皆様でしたらどのようにされるでしょうか。
同様の処理をわかりやすく説明しているサイト、書籍などあれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: この辺の記事を参考に。[plot with custom text for x axis points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3100985/9014308), [matplotlib strings as labels on x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7559242/9014308), [How to use strings as x-axis labels with Matplotlib in Python](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-use-strings-as-x-axis-labels-with-matplotlib-in-python), [<Python, matplotlib> X軸を文字で](http://nekoyukimmm.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/03/10/212216)

Comment: 実際に使用するCSV(?)データの一部をどう取り出すかとか、完全でなくても作ってみたプログラムとかあれば、テキストで提示してみてください。そうすれば具体的な助言や回答が付きやすいでしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

棒グラフの棒にラベルを表示したいってことですよね？`pyplot`モジュールの`xticks`を使えばいいと思います。

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 4, 3, 5]
plt.figure()
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.xticks(x, ['5E', '6A', '3X', '4A'])
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]