# pythonによるエラーバーの作図方法

Tags: python, matplotlib

下記のように、
項目別に、係数・95％信頼区間上限値・下限値を保持したデータフレームがあります。

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'項目': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
                   '係数': [1.255, 1.087, 0.990, 1.064, 0.885, 0.092],
                   '信頼区間上限値': [2.031, 1.535, 2.162, 1.554, 1.337, 0.382],
                   '信頼区間下限値': [0.775, 0.770, 0.453, 0.728, 0.531,0.022]})
df.set_index('項目', inplace=True)
df
```

上記のデータフレームから、下記画像のようなエラーバーのグラフを作成したいと考えています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラーバー自体は、matplotlibの errorbar() で作図できるようなのですが、ｘ軸に値を入れる必要があるようです。
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html

上記画像のように、X軸にカテゴリ値を持ちたい場合、
どのように実現可能かご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたらアドバイスいただけませんでしょうか？？

＜追記＞
kunifさまからアドバイスいただいた内容を参考に模索した結果、下記で実現できそうです。（アドバイスをアレンジしてみた部分（上下の範囲計算）他にもっといいやり方があるような気もしますが。。）

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'項目': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
                   '係数': [1.255, 1.087, 0.990, 1.064, 0.885, 0.092],
                   '信頼区間上限値': [2.031, 1.535, 2.162, 1.554, 1.337, 0.382],
                   '信頼区間下限値': [0.775, 0.770, 0.453, 0.728, 0.531,0.022]})
df['上範囲'] = df['信頼区間上限値'] - df['係数']
df['下範囲'] = df['係数'] - df['信頼区間下限値']
display(df)

ebxname = list(df['項目']) #### X軸目盛りの文字列リスト作成
ebxname.insert(0, '') #### 先頭に空文字列の挿入

ebx = [i for i in range(len(df))] #### X軸値はデータ行番号をリスト化
eby = list(df['係数']) #### Y軸値

ebyerr = [df['下範囲'], df['上範囲']] #### 
ebyerr = np.array(ebyerr) #### numpy.dnarray化

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.errorbar(ebx, eby, yerr=ebyerr, marker='.', mfc='black', ms=10, linestyle='')
ax.set_xticklabels(ebxname) #### X軸目盛り文字列設定
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 3, step=0.5))
plt.show()
```

Comment: 「エラーバー自体は、matplotlibの errorbar() で作図できるようなのですが」とありますが、グラフの作成は試行されましたか？された場合はそのコードも掲載いただくと回答しやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: documentで見つけたerrorbar()ですと、X軸に数値を入力する必要があるようでして、そもそも代入したい’項目’がカテゴリ値のため、このメソッドでの試作は断念しております。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X軸の値には `df['項目']` を指定すればよろしいかと思います。また、キャップは `capsize` で指定します。今回、`ax` は不要に見えるので `plt.errorbar()` を使用しています。

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
  '項目': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
  '係数': [1.255, 1.087, 0.990, 1.064, 0.885, 0.092],
  '信頼区間上限値': [2.031, 1.535, 2.162, 1.554, 1.337, 0.382],
  '信頼区間下限値': [0.775, 0.770, 0.453, 0.728, 0.531,0.022]
})

ebx = df['項目'] #### X値
eby = df['係数'] #### Y値
ebyerr = (
  df['係数'] - df['信頼区間下限値'], #### 下範囲
  df['信頼区間上限値'] - df['係数'], #### 上範囲
)

plt.errorbar(
  ebx, eby, yerr=ebyerr,
  marker='.', mfc='black', ms=10, linestyle='', capsize=4)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.0, 3.0, step=0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image: figure]

Comment: x軸の値は、数値ではなくカテゴリ値でも代入できたのですね。。よりシンプルな記述になって見やすくなりました。ありがとうございます！ちなみに、ebyerrの誤差範囲の指定は、ネットの記事等参考にして試行錯誤の結果なので、この方法がベスト（正統派の書き方？）かは若干自信がないのですが、もしこのあたりの知見もお持ちでしたらアドバイスいただけますか？

Comment: [Different ways of specifying error bars](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/errorbar_features.html#different-ways-of-specifying-error-bars) を参照しますと、「"Array of shape (2, N)" で指定する」と書かれていますので、適切な書き方なのだろうと思います。

Comment: なるほど、、上記サイト拝見しますと、lowerとupperを指定する、となっているようなので、配列の並びも上記順（[下範囲],[上範囲]）代入するで大丈夫そうですね、、。大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

これらの記事のように、X軸の値そのものは数値にして、目盛りの表示を文字列にすれば良いでしょう。
[Pythonで、横軸が文字列のグラフを作成したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/71750/26370)
[pyplotではxticks()、Axesではset_xticklabels()を使うんだって。](https://qiita.com/tomiyou/items/38fce051f8bd7246a0ce)

例えば質問の参照ページのさらに先にあるこちらの内容に合わせて`Axes`を使う場合：
[Errorbar function](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/statistics/errorbar.html)

'係数'や'信頼区間'の'上限値'/'下限値'を何にどう当てはめるのかは知識が無いので不明ですが、推測するとおそらくこんな感じで出来るでしょう。(範囲上下端の横線指定方法は知識不足で入っていません)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'項目': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
                   '係数': [1.255, 1.087, 0.990, 1.064, 0.885, 0.092],
                   '信頼区間上限値': [2.031, 1.535, 2.162, 1.554, 1.337, 0.382],
                   '信頼区間下限値': [0.775, 0.770, 0.453, 0.728, 0.531,0.022]})

#### df.set_index('項目', inplace=True) #### 項目のインデックス化は行わない

ebxname = list(df['項目']) #### X軸目盛りの文字列リスト作成
ebxname.insert(0, '') #### 先頭に空文字列の挿入

ebx = [i for i in range(len(df))] #### X軸値はデータ行番号をリスト化
eby = list(df['係数']) #### Y軸値

ebyerr = [df['信頼区間下限値'],df['信頼区間上限値']] #### 
ebyerr = np.array(ebyerr) #### numpy.dnarray化

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.errorbar(ebx, eby, yerr=ebyerr, marker='.', mfc='black', ms=10, linestyle='')
ax.set_xticklabels(ebxname) #### X軸目盛り文字列設定
plt.show()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！数値で作図して、後からラベルを変更する技があるのは知りませんでした。勉強になりました。いただいたコードを実行してみました。イメージ通りの図だったのですが、Y軸のラベルが、代入した配列の値とズレてしまいます。document通りの代入の仕方だと思いますが、なぜでしょう。。Y軸のラベルも何か別途指定を入れる必要があるのでしょうか？（この事例に限らず、同様のことが起こったことがあるか？ある場合は対処法をご存じでしたらアドバイスいただけると助かります！）

Comment: 実は私も良く分かっていません。X軸では紹介した記事の[axes.set_xticklabelsの注意すべき点](https://qiita.com/tomiyou/items/38fce051f8bd7246a0ce#axesset_xticklabels%E3%81%AE%E6%B3%A8%E6%84%8F%E3%81%99%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E7%82%B9)の最初の対策で、表示がズレたらその分だけズラして指定するというのを適用してみました。Y軸にもそれとかその下に書かれている対策とかを試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ありがとうございます。今一度調べてみたところ、yerrには、「y軸の誤差の値」を代入する必要があるようなので、範囲を計算してそれを代入してみたところ、やりたいことが実現できているようです。（しかしもっと良い書き方がある気もしますが。。。）トップに追記してあります。